# Rails: show post when attributes is set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integer, rendering

I am facing a weird bug and unfortunately I don't know how to investigate about it.

I am rendering certain pins on my homepage when the `integer` => `pinoftheday` is set to true. I am manually setting some pins to true.

For some pins its working well and they are appearing on the homepage, some others just don't. Btw, I am checking in my console and they are correctly set to true.

Here is a bit of code:

```
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <% if pin.pinoftheday %>
          (...) some informations about the pin 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Any ideas how I could check why some pins are not rendering? I am not writting any tests for now... I know this is stupid but I just did not learnt testing for rails.

Thank you.

EDIT: Yes, in my code it's a pin model. I wanted to used post to make it clearer. Figured it was not :) - Edited it to the correct model: pin.

Comment: what is post here ? or should it have been pin ? <% if post.pinoftheday %>
          (...) some informations about the pin 
    <% end %>

Comment: In your code `@postss` should be `@posts`, btw is there a typo error at `post`, it should be `pin`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you've defined a [local variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) in your block, and are referencing another:

```
<% @postss.each do |post| %>
  <% if post.pinoftheday %>
      ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

You'd be better using a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :pin_of_the_day, -> { where pinoftheday: true }
end
```

You'll also do well to make your `pinoftheday` column [`boolean`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html). If you're referencing `1 = true; 0 = false`, Rails handles that with a `tinyint` in your db, calling `true/false` as boolean logic. Instead of referencing the integer as a number, you can call `true` etc.

The above will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @postss = Post.pin_of_the_day
   end
end
```

This will remove the inefficient conditional logic (`<% if ...`):

```
<% @postss.each do |post| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Rich for your inputs. You were right, using a scope and calling pinoftheday from the controller is a cleaner approach. Regarding the use of a boolean, I am not sure, I have always read that it can slow down the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
 <% @postss.each do |post| %>
    <% if post.pinoftheday %>
          (...) some informations about the pin 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code then will below:

```
<% @postss.each do |pin| %>
  <% if pin.pinoftheday.nil? %>
      (...) some informations about the pin 
   <% else %>
      (...) some informations about the pin 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope will help you